# How to load a HTML file into another file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to load a file (help content) into a model popup based on the View being loaded.

I want to be able to determine the file on the fly, but for testing, I am trying to use a test file (test.html) which is in the root directory of my project.  I am using the jquery load command as follows:

```
      $("#helpdata").load("https://localhost:7249/test.html", function (response, status, xhr) {
                alert("Load was performed." + status);
            });
```

I have tried multiple variations of the url but can't get anything to work.  It gives me a status of Error when loading.  I'm not sure whether the url is relative, or fully defined.  Nothing works.  What am I missing?

Help file below.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Help", "Generic", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="modal fade" id="helpModal1" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="helpModalLabel" data-bs-backdrop="static" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="helpModalLabel">Logon Help</h1>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div style="overflow:auto">
                            <div id="helpdata">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Was expecting the file to be loaded into the specified div element.

Comment: If on the same server and folder then why not just do 

load("test.html") ? Also look in the network tab of the console

Comment: Gives status "Error" - this is jquery's one-word summary of the issue, use the network tab to determine the error details provided by the server.  The network tab will also show you the exact, full path of the file.

Comment: Also check the browser's developer tools console for other clues. Please update your question with any information you find.

Comment: Not sure, but on my computer `localhost` needs to be addressed not via https, but http. Using https gives an error...

Comment: @Johannes I always use HTTPS when running locally. I try to keep my development environment as close to production as possible. I find that some things just don't work properly over HTTP. We really need some debugging data to attempt to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Is your problem solved ? If not, could you please follow up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's [asp.net-core-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc) you either need a route, a config-exception or to put it in the `wwwroot` folder,

- Move your static `.html` file into the wwwroot folder of your project.

Do not change `$(..).load(path)` to match wwwroot - the wwwroot folder is just that, it matches the root for www requests, so project `wwwroot\file.html` -> `http://site/file.html`

Ensure your program.cs contains `app.UseStaticFiles();`  (it should do otherwise you don't get css/js etc, but you might have a custom location for static files, so move file.txt to that location if your static files are non-standard)

See: [Static files in ASP.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0) for more details

Comment: The documentation is not clear about what the url is relative to. I moved the file to wwwroot and it fixed. Thanks

Comment: ASP.Net-MVC is *MVC*.    It doesn't work like a static website.   All URLs match to Actions via Routes - they do not match to files.  For the "static files" *route*, the `http://site/` (root folder) matches to `wwwroot` in .net-core.    The *url* is always relative to the root, but the routing determines if it loads from an Action or a static file in wwwroot.